# Using Bison to parse from a char* string

Tags: c++, parsing, bison, flex-lexer

How can I make the **yyparse** function read its input from a C string?

Tried **yy_scan_buffer** (using "fp" prefix instead of "yy"):

```
extern YY_BUFFER_STATE fs_scan_string ( const char *str );

struct fs *parse(char *s)
{
fp_scan_buffer(s);
int r = fpparse();
return r == 0 ? AST : NULL;

}
```

But:

```
h1.cpp:27: error: ‘YY_BUFFER_STATE’ does not name a type
h1.cpp: In function ‘fs* parse(char*)’:
h1.cpp:32: error: ‘fp_scan_buffer’ was not declared in this scope
```

Tried using **yy_delete_buffer**, same result: was not declared in this scope.

fp.y

```
%{
#include "ft.h"
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int fplex(); 
int fperror(char *p);
int fperror(char *p) { }

using namespace std;

struct fs *AST;
bool fpworking = true;
%}

%union {
    struct fs *f;
    struct ts *t;
    std::list<struct ts *> *tl;
    std::string *s;
}

%token END_OF_FILE
MORE TOKEN HERE...

%%

s : formula '\n'    { AST = $1; fpworking = true; YYACCEPT; }
MORE RULE HERE...
```

fp.l

```
%{
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
#include "fp.tab.h"
%}

%option noyywrap

%%
[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*       { fplval.s = new std::string(fptext); return (TERM_ID); }
MORE PATTERN HERE...
```

h1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include "ft.h"

int fpparse();
int signparse();

extern bool fpworking;
extern struct fs *AST;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MORE CODE HERE...
}
```

Comment: Be aware of proper tagging.  Flex is used for the Adobe/Apache UI Framework.  Flex-lexer is used for the lexical analyzer.

Comment: The problem is in interaction between the code you have shown and code you have not shown.  Please construct a complete, self-contained, cut-down .y file that demonstrates the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the various flex-defined symbols (such as `YY_BUFFER_STATE` and `yy_scan_buffer`), the code that does so must be placed in the 3rd section of the .l file.

The issue is that these symbols are only defined in the lex.yy.c file, and not in any header file that you can `#include` elsewhere.

So all you need to do is put your `parse` code (the first block above) at the end of the .l file (after the second `%%` line) and call it from `main` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

The parser generated by `bison` does no I/O. The responsibility for reading (or otherwise acquiring) input is given to the scanner, which is often generated by `(f)lex`. The buffer management functions you refer to are part of the `flex` framework. They are not exported in any header, so you either need to use them within the code inserted into the `flex` input file, or explicitly add them to your own header file.

The traditional use of `flex` and `bison` (or, in general, derivatives of `lex` and `yacc`) relied heavily on global state variables, making it difficult to integrate multiple parsers and/or scanners into a single executable. Modifying the `yy` prefix does not really solve this problem, but it does allow multiple singletons. More recent versions of the code-generators allow the generation of `pure` parsers and scanners which take as an additional argument a structure containing the state. It's possible to add your own state to these structures, or even to combine them into a single structure. This can produce a more elegant interface, but the tools don't help you very much with API design. In any event, with pure parsers and scanners, even less state access is externally available.

In short, you should probably add your own buffer management API to your `flex` file, export its interface(s) in your own header file, and import that file in your scanner, your parser, and their consumers.